# MySQL Stored Procedure in Node.js without Promise/Await

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, google-cloud-functions

I have a backend running on Google Cloud Functions, which have a maximum running time of 9 minutes. At the same time there's a stored procedure in MySQL that could exceed the running time cap.

My question is: Is there a way to offload the execution to the MySQL instance?

I know the processing is done in the instance but it needs the connection alive. Currently if the Function is killed by Google the procedure doesn't complete because the connection is killed and then MySQL kills the execution. I need a way to detach it from the running enviroment of Cloud Functions.

Ps. I don't care about the response of the Procedure.

Comment: Mysql kills the execution if a client closes a connection. You may need to use something different from a cloud function, like pub/sub for long running processes.